# How to design this navigation bar

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, html-lists

I'm trying to build the navigation bar for my website, considering turning it into responsive design in css.

What I have in my layout is logo + site name on the left hand side, 1 button and 1 text field in central part of the bar, and 2 small squary dropdowns on the left hand side. As the screen gets smaller, some elements disappear, some get smaller, nothing ultra complicated:

[image: http://imgur.com/6AANm5z]

I was thinking of making a list, but search form can't be a part of the list, I did try to create separate divs that group objects as per image, but the result wasn't really satisfactory (issues with float:).

What would be your suggestion on building such navigation bar, considering responsive layout?

Thanks!

Comment: You may be having problems that can be solved with "clearfixing". See [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did my own homework and ended up solving my own issue. First I divided header into 3 divs (navleft, center, and navright), but since I wanted to have fixed gap between two middle elements, I splitted 'center' div into 3 - center-left, center (containing 10px padding only) and center-right.

In css I defined widths, floats etc in order to make the navigation bar responsive and ended up with a working header, that also has 'search' field with 'go' button. Html code:

```
<div id="top-bar"> 
    <div class="navleft">
        <div class="logo"><img src="logo.png"></div>
        <div id="site-title"><a href="#">WEBSITE</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="center-left">               
        <div class="new rounded">
        <a href="#"><span class="inline">NEW</span><img class="make" src="make.png"></a></div>          
    </div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="center-right">
        <div class="searchbox rounded">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button class="mglass right"><a href="#"></a></button>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="navright">                                  
        <div id="yours" class="rounded">
            <div><a href="#"><img src="yours.png"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="logged" class="rounded">
            <div><a href="#"><img class="avatar rounded" src="avatar4.jpg"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="username">Ricardo<br>Pindollini</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using Bootstrap framework?
You can easily design responsive navbar.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know bootstrap and I already used it for a website, but in this case I'm rather trying to go for pure html + css combo. Not sure why with css and html you can do amazing stuff yet things that in my opinion should take 15 minutes to programm, are overcomplicated